# How to convert string list to JSON string array in Bash?

Tags: arrays, json, string, bash, jq

How can I convert a variable in Bash with a string list containing newlines, like this

```
groups="group_1
group_2
group_3"
```

to a JSON string array:

```
{
    [ "group_1", "group_2", "group 3" ]
}
```

Is this possible with jq?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your jq has `inputs` then the simplest would probably be to use it:

```
jq -ncR '[inputs]' <<< "$groups"
["group1","group2","group3"]
```

Otherwise, here are three alternatives:

```
jq -c -n --arg groups "$groups" '$groups | split("\n")' 

echo -n "$groups" | jq -cRs 'split("\n")'

echo "$groups" | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n") | map(select(length>0))'
```

In any case, the array can easily be incorporated into a JSON object, e.g. by extending the filter with `| {groups: .}`

If you really want to produce invalid JSON, consider:

```
printf "%s" "$groups" | jq -Rrsc 'split("\n") | "{ \(.) }"'
```

Output:

```
{ ["group_1","group_2","group_3"] }
```

#### Note on select(length>0)

Consider:

```
 jq -Rsc 'split("\n")' <<< $'a\nb'
 ["a","b",""]
```

The reason for including `select(length>0)` is to avoid the trailing "".

If $groups contains consecutive newlines, and if it is important to retain the empty strings, then you might want to use `[:-1]`, e.g.

```
jq -cRs 'split("\n")[:-1]' <<< "$groups"
["group1","group2","group3"]
```

If your jq does not support `[:-1]`, make the 0 explicit: `[0:-1]`

Comment: The fact that `[:-1]` serves to suppress reporting the trailing `\n` as an _additional_ array element is surprising, given that even without it, interior lines are reported _without_ their trailing `\n`, and, curiously, `[:-1]` doesn't trim an _additional_ character from the end. Generally, `split()` employs _separator_ logic rather than _terminator_ logic.

Comment: As this is primarily a `jq` question, I'd recommend using `printf '%s' "$groups"` instead of `echo -n`; then you can use the shorter `jq` filter with any shell without worrying about how `echo` will interpret the`-n` "option".