# Convert a JSON string to an array in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, asp.net-web-api

Am having a curl function  to fetch data from webapi. the web API returns a Json String of format `["Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5"]`. I need to extract the data into an array in the bash script so that I could use the Names to loop in the rest of the code.
My required format is like `arr[0]=Name1 ,...., arr[n]=Namen`

Comment: [Converting a JSON object into a Bash associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26717277/608639), [How to convert string list to JSON string array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44477810/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

For elements without newlines you could do something as simple as this:

```
$ readarray -t arr < <(jq -r  '.[]' <<< '["Name1","Name2"]')
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="Name1" [1]="Name2")
```

---

Reading this [`jq` request for NUL-delimited output](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1271), this will allow elements with newlines as well:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' item; do
    arr+=("$item")
done < <(jq -j  '.[]|(. + "\u0000")' <<< '["Name1","Na\nme2"]')

# with bash 4.4 or later
$ readarray -d '' arr < <(jq -j  '.[]|(. + "\u0000")' <<< '["Name1","Na\nme2"]')

$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="Name1" [1]=$'Na\nme2')
```

Comment: +1. Possible improvement: If we *really* don't trust what the remote server is providing, you might consider making the latter remove any NUL literals from the incoming JSON so hostile values can't split themselves into new elements. That said, that's a tiny quibble, and I'm not sure I've always consistently done it myself in every answer I have here.